# Is there a way to call spinOnce for a specific subscriber?

Tags: ros, spinonce, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Inside my node I have several callbacks. I want to avoid using spinOnce() inside my node as much as possible since the current job should always finish what it is doing before the next callback begins. However, there is one instance which I need to wait on a particular message before continuing. The current solution is to run spinOnce() in a loop, but this is not the way it should be done.

Is there a nice way of doing this? I've read a little about creating my own queuing system, but I would like to find a way that requires the fewest amount of changes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258381/is-there-a-way-to-call-spinonce-for-a-specific-subscriber?/) by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Section 4 in the [roscpp callbacks and spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) describes how to assign different subscribers to different callback queues, and then you can spin the one callback queue for your subscriber without invoking callbacks for your other subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-04-03**:
This is what I ended up doing. Created a separate nodehandle, queue, and used `callAvailable` on that queue.